# Is there a java API to generate xml with an inline schema definition

Tags: java, xml, jakarta-ee, xsd

I want to generate the xml file that holds its schema as well as the xml data contain using java,as per my knowledge it is possible in C# .NET.Is it possible in java???

My XML file should be look like as given below.

```
<transaction>
  <xs:schema id="transaction" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
    <xs:element name="transaction" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:element name="id">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="in" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="sn" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="book" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="author" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
               </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="data">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="dateTime" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="key" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="productData">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="dateTime" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="key" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
  <id>
    <in>computer</in>
    <sn>1234567</sn>
    <book>JAVA</book>
    <author>klen</author>
  </id>
  <data>
    <dateTime>2011-06-24T17:08:36.3727674+05:30</dateTime>
    <key>Err</key>
  </data>
</transaction>
```

In my given example my xml file contain data as well as schema I need to generate this type of file from schema using java.

I can only create the xml part using jaxb and main part of my code is look like as

```
Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
        jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT,true);
            jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT,true);
        jaxbMarshaller.marshal(transaction, file);
        jaxbMarshaller.marshal(transaction, System.out);
```

but I can not add the inline xml schema part with my xml file.

@jtahlborn ok I will try to dig it up thanks for your help.I have another question I heard about that stax is better than dom to xml write,so I want to use stax is it possible to set namespace and other thing. I have another question is it true that jaxb is only use to convert xml to xml schema(un marshaling) and xml schema to xml(marshaling) and if I need to write xml file then we need to use jaxb[DOM,STAX(stream based reading writing),SAX(stream only reading)] .

Comment: What's the main question? What have you tried?

Comment: @Adel I want to add my schema in my generated xml file it is possible in C# but is it possible in java.

Comment: @josh I google it for java I got answer that JAXB by marchaling we get xml file from schema but we did not add schema definition with that xml file.

Comment: @josh is it possible to generate xml file from schema in using jaxp?

Comment: @I am waiting to get a valid answer for this question I am trying to do this in java can you have any idea.

Comment: @moin I think you're looking to marshal an xml document from java with an "inline schema" definition. You may want to phrase your question accordingly.

Comment: @yeap uff you are absolutely right sorry actually I do not know the appropriate term.thanks.but do you how to do that in java?

Comment: @jtahlborn actually I am new in java can u give some code snips for step 3 and 4 because I can not understand how to add my schema generated xml file after the dom generated schema structure in dom generated xml file after the <transaction> tag

Comment: @jtahlborn ok I will try to dig it up thanks for your help.I have another question I heard about that stax is better than dom to xml write,so I want to use stax is it possible to set namespace and other thing. I have another question is it true that jaxb is only use to convert xml to xml schema(un marshaling) and xml schema to xml(marshaling) and if I need to write xml file then we need to use jaxb[DOM,STAX(stream based reading writing),SAX(stream only reading)] .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would:

1. create a DOM document from your schema (e.g. parse the schema file)
2. create a new DOM document
3. add the root node to your new DOM document (e.g. "transaction")
4. append the schema document from step 1. as the first child of the "transaction" element
5. append the actual document data as subsequent children of the "transaction" element

Alternately, if you want to use JAXB to generate the "main" xml output, then you can:

1. populate jaxb models (created from the schema)
2. marshal the jaxb models to a DOM document
3. create a DOM document from your schema (e.g. parse the schema file)
4. insert the schema document from step 3. as the first child of the "transaction" element in your DOM document

(with a few jaxb config tricks, you could probably get your Transaction model to have an Element "schema" property, and then you could set that property from the parsed schema doc and marshal the whole model at one time)

Comment: it is very tedious work isnot possible to do that in any easy way like c#.using jaxb or other API in java?

Comment: @moin - i don't know c#, so i don't know what "like c#" means.  there are a variety of means of generating xml in java, but without more details, only a c# & java expert can probably give you more targeted advice.

Comment: yeap you are right actually I want to know that can I generate xml file with inline schema in java using jaxb or other api?actually I did not show the original xml file which is very large in size so it is very hard to code add node manually in xml by manual coding so I want this type of api where xml file will generate with inline schema I only set the value of the node using set() method?

Comment: actually I am new in java can u give some code snips for step 3 and 4 because I can not understand how to add my schema generated xml file after the dom generated schema structure in dom generated xml file after the <transaction> tag

Comment: @moin - you should be able to find plenty of other examples on this site which show you how to parse a file to a DOM document and how to manipulate Nodes/Elements in a DOM document.

Comment: ok I will try to dig it up thanks for your help.I have another question I heard about that stax is better than dom to xml write,so I want to use stax is it possible to set namespace and other thing.

I have another question is it true that jaxb is only use to convert xml to xml schema(un marshaling) and xml schema to xml(marshaling) and if I need to write xml file then we need to use jaxb[DOM,STAX(stream based reading writing),SAX(stream only reading)] .